# Is it possible to learn XOR using only threshold activation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Correct me if I am wrong here, but it is possible to implement the XOR function with a minimum of 3 gates (NAND, OR)->(AND) using a 1-layer network. But is it possible to train the network correctly, having each perceptron use only a threshold activation function and a perceptron training rule? i.e. use the perceptron learning rule and not the delta learning rule.

So far my only solution in theory would be to train each perceptron individually for their specific task (i.e. NAND OR and AND) before forming the actual network, but that defeats the point of a network that learns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use the perceptron algorithm to train a multilayer network. You need gradient-based learning, and the perceptron algorithm does not produce gradients; it optimizes for the non-differentiable zero-one loss.

Comment: Thanks, this is the conclusion I came to whilst going through my course work - just needed some confirmation.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple as we remember that perceptron law deal with single layer(one gate,or,and,either nand gate)but xor gate contains more than one combination of (and,or and nand )gates that is why perceptron law not satisfy XOR GAT